# How can i match the text file with some keywords in other file

Tags: keyword, textmatching

I have one text file with some data. now i have a list of keywords in other text file file.

Now i want to do the maching so that i can find out how many keywords from the second text file are in the first file.

I am not a big programmer , so is there any easy way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided both the files are not huge, this could be a solution

```
f=open("textfile")
f2=open("keywordfile")
text=f.read().split()
keyword=f2.read.split()
print list(set(text)&set(keyword))
```

Note: The above code is in python